# finding a cancelling polynomial of an algebraic number

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

(Note: I am not looking for the minimal polynomial)

I want to find a polynomial in $\mathbb Q[X]$ which cancels $\sqrt[4]{2}+1$.

I do :
$$(\sqrt[4]{2}+1)^2=\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt[4]{2}+1$$
From then on, either I continue isolating the $\sqrt[4]{2}$ and $\sqrt2$ on the right:
$$(\sqrt[4]{2}+1)^2-1=\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt[4]{2}$$ and I go on putting the rationals on the left side and squaring... but it rapidly becomes tedious and longer than I thought. On the other hand, if I do :
$$(\sqrt[4]{2}+1)^2-1-\sqrt{2}=2\sqrt[4]{2}$$
I can rapidly find a polynomial in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})[X]$ which cancels $\alpha$.
$$((\sqrt[4]{2}+1)^2-(1+\sqrt{2}))^2=(2\sqrt[4]{2})^2=4\sqrt2$$

So
$$P(X)=(X^2-(1+\sqrt2))^2-4\sqrt2$$ which is :
$$P(X)=X^4-(2+2\sqrt2)X^2+3-2\sqrt2$$
 cancels $\sqrt[4]{2}+1$.

Now does that help me find a polynomial in $\mathbb Q[X]$ which cancels $\sqrt[4]{2}+1$ ?

Same question with $\sqrt[4]{2}+i$ : we can easily find a polynomial in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})[X]$ which cancels it : (we define $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{2}$)
$$(\alpha +i)^2=\alpha^2+2\alpha i-1$$
$$(\alpha +i)^2+1-\alpha^2=2\alpha i$$ so
$$(X^2-(1-\alpha^2))^2+4\alpha^2$$ which is 
$$(X^2-(1-\sqrt2))^2+4\alpha^2$$
cancels it.

Is there a link between the cancelling polynomials in $\mathbb Q[X]$ and the ones in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})[X]$ ? Or in a more general way, does knowing a cancelling polynomial in a middle extension help finding one in the first field ? (Like, if $K\subset L\subset M$, does knowing a cancelling polynomial of an element of $M$ over $L$ help finding one over $K$ ?

Comment: What about $(X-1)^4 - 2$?

Comment: And, even if it is not said so, you are looking for the minimal polynomial...

Comment: Of course ! Thanks Siméon. I could still use an answer to the general question.

Comment: You may want to look at resultants and how CAS handle towers of algebraic extensions. -- As an example, if $f(a)=0$ and $g(b)=0$, then $c=a+b$ is a root of $Res_T(f(T),g(X-T))$.

Comment: A small fragment of Magma code that can be evaluated on http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/ : R<X,Y>:=PolynomialRing(Rationals(),2); f1:=(Y-X)^4-2; f2:=X-1; Resultant(f1,f2,X);

Comment: In this example it is trivial, X gets replaced by 1. To see something happen set f2=X^2+1 or f2=X^2-X-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[If](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem) a polynomial with real coefficients $P(x)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ has an irreducible root of the form $a+bi$ , then its conjugate $a-bi$ must also be among them. Obviously, $\mathbb{Q}[x]\subset\mathbb{R}[x]$. Furthermore, according to [Vieta's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), the various sums of products of these roots must also be rational. In our case, $x_{_{1,2}}=\sqrt[4]2\pm i\to x_{_{1}}\cdot x_{_{2}}=\sqrt2+1$. Since $\prod x_k\in\mathbb{Q}$ , it follows that $x_{_{3}}\cdot x_{_{4}}=1-\sqrt2$, implying $x_{_{3,4}}=i(\sqrt[4]2\pm1)$. So far their sum is still non-rational, since $\sum_{1}^4x_k=2\sqrt[4]2(1+i)\not\in\mathbb{Q}$ . This can only be rectified by finding $x_{_{5-8}}$ so that $\sum_5^8x_k=-2\sqrt[4]2(1+i)$. Judging by what we got so far, it's not hard to guess that $x_{_{5-8}}=-x_{_{1-4}}$ Indeed, it can be verified using specialized computer software that $P(x)=\prod_1^8(x-x_k)=x^8+4x^6+2x^4+28x^2+1$ is the *minimal polynomial* for $\sqrt[4]2+i$.